# explanation for: to "playback" media content

Tags: meaning, etymology

How come in English one talks about being able to "playback" media content, like music or movies, instead of just "play"? Why is -back added to the word? What is the origin of the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is given by [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/playback) to mean:

> The replaying of previously recorded sound or moving images.

The reason -back was added, was because, this was a "replay" of a previously recorded media article.

The origin of the expression is from the phrase ["play back"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/playback) (which is different from "playback")

> Origin:
>   1925–30;  noun use of verb phrase play back

"Play back" is [defined as :](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play_back)

> (idiomatic, transitive) To replay a recording.

Comment: +1. Note that the verb is "play back" (two words), not "playback" - you can tell this because you can say "I want to play it back", but not "*I want to playback it". However "playback" *is* used as a noun ("Instant playback is one of the advantages of these models").